# strange error with ls on Slackware 15

Tags: ls

Very strange error on Slackware 15 using ls
Let's see...

ls is aliased

```
alias ls
alias ls='/bin/ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

ls return error

```
ls
/bin/ls: invalid option -- ' '
```

unalias it and works fine

```
unalias ls
ls
```

I made source and error return

```
source.bashrc
ls
    /bin/ls: invalid option -- ' '
```

This is bashrc

```
# Aliases
alias ldapsearch="ldapsearch -Y gssapi"
alias parallel="parallel --will-cite"
alias free="free -h"
alias wget="wget -c"
alias dmesg="dmesg -eT"
alias d='/bin/ls $LS_OPTIONS'
alias ls='/bin/ls $LS_OPTIONS'
alias rsync="rsync -avAXHhSP -e 'ssh -Y'"
alias at="at -m"

# Variables
export LS_OPTIONS="-F -b -T 0 --color=auto"
export LANG="it_IT.utf8"
export MINICOM="-c on"
export LESSOPEN="|lesspipe.sh %s"
export LESS="-M"
export HISTSIZE=5500
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S "
export MAIL=/var/spool/mail/$USER
export EDITOR=vim
export COLUMNS=120
export NLS_LANG=Italian_ITALY.UTF8
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
export MBOX=$HOME/.mbox

# Binds
bind '"\C-f": forward-search-history'
```

If I close the shell and re-open (run a new xfce4-terminal), error disappear and ls works fine.
I use Xfce4-terminal

Comment: Is it possible that the space in the alias is not actually a space but is some other whitespace character? Test this theory by running `alias ls='/bin/ls $LS_OPTIONS'` interactively and then seeing if `ls` now works or still fails

Comment: When `ls` fails, run: `ls 2>&1 | cat -A` and paste the output to your question.

Comment: Wait, if the problem disappears when you close the shell and open a new one, when does it appear? Every shell is new when you open it...

Comment: Sometimes appear

Comment: Does it appear if you start new `bash` without closing the old one, just starting it from your current shell (after the problem appears)?

Comment: No, if I start a new shell the problem disappear

Comment: Ok, so when it happen, also try running `/bin/ls $LS_OPTIONS`, and `echo "$LS_OPTIONS | cat -A`. Paste the result of all those commands (along with `ls 2>&1 | cat -A` to your question.

Comment: "If I close the shell and re-open" : Do you mean "if I close Xfce4-terminal & relaunch it" ?

Comment: yes, run a new xfce4-terminal

Comment: The only way that specific message is generated, on GNU/Linux, with glibc and GNU ls, is through what @ChrisDavies said: by having a Unicode character visually identical to space in `LS_OPTIONS` and then sourcing the file in which `LS_OPTIONS` and `ls` alias were defined. Adding the call to `ls` to the end of _~/.bashrc_ and doing, for example, `bash ~/.bashrc` should not produce an error in such a case (tested on Artix Linux, glibc 2.39, GNU Bash 5.2.26, GNU coreutils 9.4). Note: the character is shown as diamond with question mark in the error message on test system.

Comment: To try to solve this, rewrite the `export LS_OPTIONS=...` and `alias ls=...` lines using an English keyboard, in some sane text editor like vim or nano, save _~/.bashrc_ and report if there is still an error.

Comment: Add this comment as answer so I can close this question please